# How to construct a joint pdf, other than the independent coupling, given two marginal pdf's?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, coupling

I am trying to find joint densities for which the marginal densities are $f_U(u) = 2\exp(-2u), u\geq 0$ and $f_V (v) = \exp (-v), v \geq 0 $. Of course I can take the joint pdf $f(u,v) = f_U(u) \cdot f_V(v)$ (by assuming independence). But how can I construct other joint densities for which the marginals are $f_U$, $f_V$?

**Attempts so far**

*Attempt 1* I have tried to construct a joint pdf along a line. Something like $f(x,y) = \exp (-y) 1 _{ \{ 2y = x\} } (x,y)$. But that does not seem to do the trick because $f$ integrates to 0.

*Attempt 2* Let $X_1, X_2 \sim \text{EXP} (1)$ be independent random variables and put $U=X_1$ and $V=\text{min} \{ X_1, X_2 \}$. Then the joint pdf will be
\begin{align*}
f _{U,V} (u,v) = \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial u \partial v} \mathbb{P} (U\leq u, V\leq v) =  \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial u \partial v} \mathbb{P} (X_1\leq u, \min \{ X_1, X_2 \} \leq v).
\end{align*}
I do not know how to proceed further. I think I have to integrate $f_U (x) f_V (y)$ over some area $A (u,v) \subseteq \mathbb{R} ^2$ in order to obtain $\mathbb{P} (U\leq u, V\leq v)$ and then take the double partial derivative to find $f_{U,V}$.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried to construct a joint pdf along a line. Something like $f(x,y) = \exp (-y) 1 _{ \{ 2y = x\} } (x,y)$. But that does not seem to do the trick because $f$ integrates to 0. I really don't see how to approach this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F_U(u), F_V(v)$ be the c.d.f.s corresponding to the given marginal p.d.f.s $f_U(u), f_V(v).$ Then $F_U(U)$ and $F_V(V)$ (note that the arguments are denoted by capital letters this time, so these are random variables) are uniformly distributed in $[0,1].$ Those are their marginal distributions. Their joint distribution is an example of a [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)). A copula is any probability distribution of a random variable taking values in the cube $[0,1]^n$ whose marginal distributions are uniform in the interval.

Given any copula, you can take any of the marginals – call it $X$ – and let $U= F_U^{-1}(X),$ where $F$ is a continuous c.d.f., and you $F_U$ is then the c.d.f. of the random variable $U$ that is defined that way.

So the question is: what copulas exist? See the linked Wikipedia article.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So far as I understand it, $F_U (U), F_V(V) \sim U(0,1)$ and the joint distribution of $(F_U(U), F_V(V))$ is a copula. But I don't understand your last paragraph. I think you are saying the following. Let $(X,Y)$ be distributed according to a copula $C$. Then $F^{-1} _U (X) \sim F_U$ and $F^{-1} _V (Y) \sim F_V$ where $F_U, F_V$ are the desired cdf's. Then $(F^{-1} _U (X), F^{-1} _V (Y) )$ follows a joint distribution that can be found through the copula $C$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @JanTinbergen1991 : Yes, but also that there is a one-to-one correspondence between copulas and absolutely continuous probability distributions.